# Nested REGEX lookup

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

I'm trying to extract relevant information from a text blob for purchasing food items. Is there a way to recourse after a group match and extract the relevant information? For example I'd like to get a list of statuses and their state "DOWN" and the time 120 min / timestamp. I'm going through the documentation and having some difficulty with the recursive aspect of grouping.

```
(Orange|GRAPE|APPLE)+.*?(?=(?:\.)|$)


Food: APPLE
    Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).
    Advertising Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).

Food: Orange
    Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).
    Advertising Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).

Food: GRAPE
    Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).
    Advertising Purchase status is DOWN after not receiving any purchases for more than 120 min. Last purchase received time is: 06/23/2010 11:20:21 EDT (-0400).
```

**Current Aproach:**

https://regex101.com/r/L4M8lO/1

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/7Ji64u/1

Comment: Thank you Wiktor for your response. That's very close to the requirements and I'm starting to understand your approach by checking the characters and their groupings. Under each Food item is an unknown amount or distinct statuses. How would I work (?R) into your query? I believe that's the proper way to do a recursive subquery at least

Comment: You do not need any pattern recursion here

Comment: Wiktor perhaps you're correct in your assertion. The pattern doesn't fit the requirements so my assumption would be I need to recurse over the groups 2 - 4 to find all statuses. http://prntscr.com/qo91yu

Comment: I doubt [this](https://regex101.com/r/7Ji64u/2) will fix it, and if I am right, you can't do the thing with a single regex.

Comment: I see what you mean for trying a single regex. It looks like I will need to do two which isn't all that bad. I'm testing this regExp and it doesn't work for ecmaScript. Do you have any insight into converting it?

Comment: . I figured out how to convert it to ecma by removing \s and adding additional \'s

Comment: [This](https://regex101.com/r/7Ji64u/3) is ECMAScript version.